# Python priority queue pops in descending order

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

q = PriorityQueue()

q.put((2, 'code'))
q.put((1, 'eat'))
q.put((3, 'sleep'))

while not q.empty():
    next_item = q.get()
    print(next_item)

# Result:
#   (1, 'eat')
#   (2, 'code')
#   (3, 'sleep')
```

What can i do so that it will pop in a reverse order? ie descending

Comment: Can you negate the index when you populate the queue, i.e., `q.put((-2, 'code'))`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel if you're going to change those values, you might as well change them to be the order you want

Comment: sure but what if he has a lot of items? multiplying with -1 is less error-prone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use this method as a trick multiply by -1 to inverse the order  :

```
q = PriorityQueue()

q.put((2*(-1), 'code'))
q.put((1*(-1), 'eat'))
q.put((3*(-1), 'sleep'))
while not q.empty():
    next_item = q.get()
    print(next_item)
```

output:

```
(-3, 'sleep')
(-2, 'code')
(-1, 'eat')
```

Comment: yes you can put as a simple way i use this methode @ThomasBlankenhorn

Comment: Yep. Same idea. Your implementation  has the virtue of being simpler, but mine is more general because the original numbers at the beginning might be part of the actual data and you might not want to mess with them. Whatever works. @Ghassen

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the behavior of the queue class. I would decorate the items before queuing them, and un-decorate them after retrieving them, something like this:

```
def decorated(item):
    return (-item[0],) + item

def undecorated(item):
    return item[1:]
```

That gives you items that will queue up in the right order:

```
>>> decorated(1, 'eat')
(-1, 1, 'eat')
>>> undecorated(-1, 1, 'eat')
(1, 'eat')
```

That way you can say `q.put(decorated(item))` instead of `q.put(item)`. Analogously, you retrieve the item by saying  `undecorated(q.get())` instead of `q.get()`. After this, the rest of your code keeps working as it did before.

Answer (score 0):

The `PriorityQueue` API let's you define the order.

If you want those strings in the opposite order, just reverse the `int` values in the tuples:

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

q = PriorityQueue()

q.put((2, 'code'))
q.put((3, 'eat'))
q.put((1, 'sleep'))

while not q.empty():
    next_item = q.get()
    print(next_item)

#(1, 'sleep')
#(2, 'code')
#(3, 'eat')
```

There is no way to invert the behavior of the `PriorityQueue` and python's (non-threadsafe) `heapq` uses the same ordering. But I see your point, the real name should probably be "`MinPriorityQueue`" since `1` is always first in this structure.

Comment: If the sorted order (ie rank of each item) can trivially be derived from the "priority", you don't need a PriorityQueue, you can just use a list. eg, `lst[rank(item)] = item; for next_item in lst: pass`. This problem only becomes interesting if you need to sort based on priority, but the sorted order cannot be trivially derived.